# How can I get Yahoo Mail Mobile App for my Nokia Lumia 720?

Tags: 8.0, lumia

Yahoo says the Mail App that came with my Nokia Lumia 720 is not secure enough, that I should get the most secure Mobile Mail App from Google App Store

Comment: That would be odd advice, as apps in the Google App Store will not work on Windows Phones, where are you seeing this warning?

Answer (score 1):

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/96841/101624

As stated in a previous question about the security of the Mail app, the app is only secure if you are using a secure mail server. The message given to you from Yahoo might be entailing that windows phones cannot use secure protocols for sending emails. The mail app is secure as I have been using it for 5 years and have had no security issues. The Mail app on Windows phone does use SMTP(Simple Mail Transfer Protocol).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party apps like:

1. [Mail](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/mail/9wzdncrfj4k1)
2. [Flow Mail](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/flow-mail/9nblggh4lxqq)
3. [Mail Plus](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/mail-plus/9nblggh093hp)